# Is it possible to use the click event of a read-only checkbox in MS Access?

Tags: ms-access, vba

No. I assumed I could use the click event as opposed to the AfterUpdate event for a checkbox in a Read Only data source.

To test this I wrote the following

```
Sub chk_MyCheckbox

msgbox "Hello"

End Sub
```

And nothing happens. Obviously, this is because the checkbox is bound to a field in a read-only data source.  I realize this is because it thinks I actually want to check the box and it can't. So I was hoping to only use the click event and NOT actually edit the checkbox.  I do have a hyperlinked field from this same read only source where the click event works. So I was thinking I could use the click event of the checkbox.

I'd like the datasheet to respond as if it were actually allowed to be checked and I will programatically change the value behind the scenes and then refresh the sub form.

One idea I had is to populate a temp table with the data from the read only data source.  Is there another way I could approach this?

Comment: You should include a clear problem statement and an explanation of what you have tried so far, including example code.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the *AfterUpdate* event, as a read-only or locked checkbox will cannot update via the UI.

However, you can use the *OnClick* event as long as the checkbox is enabled.